# Stream mp3/asx/pls/m3u webradio android

Tags: java, android, streaming

I'm building an android app that is basicaly a directory of up to 10 local radio.
The app should allow the user to listen to any of thosne radios. All i got for those radio i a stream URL (pls/asx,/m3u/mp3).
How should i implement the MediaPlayer to stream all those format?

thansk in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about PLS but I know for sure that M3U isn't currently supported. You may want to go the flash route on this one; if you target is Froyo of course.

Comment: I would like it to be compatible with lower version of the SDK. Is there any radio streaming format that is fully supported par the 1.6 SDK for example?

Comment: I would like to build a framework on wich other radios may plug to add their station. therefor, if there is out there one or two supported radio streaming format then i would be able to require them to use it.